# How can I identify whether or not a video card supports WDDM 2.2

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I see lots of pages that around the April 2017 period talked about NVidia releasing drivers with WDDM 2.2 support. I also see a Microsoft page ([here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install_the_tools#immersive_headset_development)) that specifically mentioned the GTX 1050 GPU as one of the GPUs that meets requirements for something that makes use of WDDM 2.2. I put a GTX 1050 card in a Windows 10 Creator's Update machine (Build 16257.1) and tried NVidia's GeForce drivers from version 381.65 (the April version in which 2.2 support is said to exists) and later. I end up with WDDM 2.1 support consistently across many driver versions (which is below requirements for what I need).  This includes the beta/experimental drivers.

Given an NVidia GPU is there any good way to identify whether or not it has WDDM 2.2 support before I buy it? NVidia mentions support in their drivers but there is no mention on how to identify whether or not it is supported on a specific card. Secondary to that question is there something special I need to do to get a WDDM 2.2 driver on the GTX 1050? Or is the above mentioned Microsoft page in error in calling out the card as one that has WDDM 2.2 support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `dxdiag.exe` it shows the WDDM version:

[image]

This is the output from my Windows 10 v1703 VM in VMware and it only supports 1.3.

So get the [latest driver from nVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us), install this driver for the GTX 1050 and look which WDMM version it supports, when I tested a RS3 build on my laptop I got WDDM2.2 driver fro my older AMD Radeon HD77xxM so your newer card from nVIDIA should also have 2.2

Comment: I'm about to purchase some cards. Is there any way that this can be determined before taking it off the shelf, purchasing it, and taking it home? After lots of diggint around I found that the 1050 Does **not** have VR support despite Microsoft's page listing it as one that does. I was hoping there were a single source of truth about these cards so I can avoid doing a purchase and a return.

Answer (score 1):

I came across an almost meaningful error message last night. It told me that "This computer does not support VR. To support VR you need atleast a GTX 1050. Your computer has a GTX 1050."

I found what the problem was though. The particular computer I had picked up and placed the video card into had an older processor.  It was a Core i5 but the 4 digit number after the processor name was lower than what was is needed for WDDM 2.2. So it was using WDDM 2.1 instead. I grabbed another similarly configured computer with a more recent processor and things worked fine.